# How to get the data of which admin user has updated the products in admin backend magento 2

Tags: magento2, products, backend

I want to display user modified product changes and also his name and updated date in admin product edit page .

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Do you want a history of changes ? Or do you want it to be replaced with the last changes ?

Comment: I created custom module for admin side . whenever we open the product it should display the history of changes and also who changed it